# what's wrong with this simple bash command?

Tags: linux, bash

$i is not working... it's making me crazy!

```
for i in {1..200}; 
do echo "/scratch/inputTest/prob/timit.test.pg.list_10_$i_prob.bin" >> longProbList; 
done
```

in the file there is just

```
/scratch/inputTest/prob/timit.test.pg.list_10_.bin
/scratch/inputTest/prob/timit.test.pg.list_10_.bin
/scratch/inputTest/prob/timit.test.pg.list_10_.bin
/scratch/inputTest/prob/timit.test.pg.list_10_.bin
/scratch/inputTest/prob/timit.test.pg.list_10_.bin
/scratch/inputTest/prob/timit.test.pg.list_10_.bin
/scratch/inputTest/prob/timit.test.pg.list_10_.bin
/scratch/inputTest/prob/timit.test.pg.list_10_.bin
/scratch/inputTest/prob/timit.test.pg.list_10_.bin
/scratch/inputTest/prob/timit.test.pg.list_10_.bin
/scratch/inputTest/prob/timit.test.pg.list_10_.bin
/scratch/inputTest/prob/timit.test.pg.list_10_.bin
/scratch/inputTest/prob/timit.test.pg.list_10_.bin
/scratch/inputTest/prob/timit.test.pg.list_10_.bin
/scratch/inputTest/prob/timit.test.pg.list_10_.bin
/scratch/inputTest/prob/timit.test.pg.list_10_.bin
/scratch/inputTest/prob/timit.test.pg.list_10_.bin
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It thinks your variable name is `$i_prob` since an underscore is a valid character for a variable name. Use `${i}` to fix this:

```
for i in {1..200}; 
do echo "/scratch/inputTest/prob/timit.test.pg.list_10_${i}_prob.bin" >> longProbList; 
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You've forgotten the " " around $i

```bsh
for i in {1..200}; 
do echo "/scratch/inputTest/prob/timit.test.pg.list_10_"$i"_prob.bin" >> longProbList; 
done
```

Comment: `${i}` is a much more common way to do this.

Comment: @Aaaron says who? Mine is better readable. Even the stackoverflow syntax highlighter recognizes mine better.

Comment: I admire your bravado; but I agree with @Aaron.  You are correct that your mechanism also works, but using the `${var}` notation is generally better, especially if the variable value contains spaces and they must be preserved (which is not the case here, I agree).

Comment: The following does not have the same output: `i="a  z"; echo "eee"$i"bbb"; echo "eee${i}bbb"` (2 spaces between a and z). Using `${i}` keeps the 2 spaces between a and z.

Comment: @jfgagne ok I agree. Thanks for your example script.